# Python multiple assignment throws error but separate assignment does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-precedence, assignment-operator, order-of-execution

I'm reversing a linked list, but multiple assignment breaks this function while separate assignments do not. Could someone explain the execution difference between these two code sections?

I know that the right side of the expression is evaluated before assignment, but nowhere do I access None.next if that is the case as far as I can see.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

def clear():
    print("------------------------------------------")

def isPalindrome(A):
    if A is None:
        return True

    # get length
    cur, length = A, 1
    while cur.next is not None:
        cur = cur.next
        length += 1

    # go to second half
    cur, index = A, 0
    while index < (length + 1) / 2:
        cur = cur.next
        index += 1


    # start reversing
    prev = None
    while cur is not None:
        # this throws error? what is the difference?
        # cur, prev, cur.next = cur.next, cur, prev
        temp = cur.next
        cur.next = prev
        prev = cur
        cur = temp

    # now prev has reversed second half
    secondHalf = prev
    firstHalf = A

    # traverse both halves, comparing Ll[n] with Ll[length - 1 - n]
    while secondHalf is not None and firstHalf is not None:
        if firstHalf.val != secondHalf.val:
            return False

        firstHalf = firstHalf.next
        secondHalf = secondHalf.next

    return True

# even length simple case
def isPalindromeTest():
    A = Node(1, Node(1, Node(1, Node(1))))

    clear()
    print(isPalindrome(A))

isPalindromeTest()
```

I expect the commented line

```
# cur, prev, cur.next = cur.next, cur, prev
```

to be equivalent to

```
temp = cur.next
cur.next = prev
prev = cur
cur = cur.next
```

Error message if I use the first code section:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linked_lists.py", line 1089, in <module>
    isPalindromeTest()
  File "linked_lists.py", line 1052, in isPalindromeTest
    print(isPalindrome(A))
  File "linked_lists.py", line 1027, in isPalindrome
    cur, prev, cur.next = cur.next, cur, prev
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Implying that I am accessing None.next, which in this context it would have to be prev.next if anything?
```

Second code section:

```
------------------------------------------
True
```

Could someone explain the execution difference between these two code sections?

Comment: What was the point of assigning to `temp`, if you aren't going to use it? The last line is accessing a `cur.next` that is incorrect because `cur.next` has already been reassigned. `cur = temp` would have worked there.

Comment: Does it still throw an error? (What is the error?)

Comment: edited, meant to have cur = temp at the end

Comment: Added the error message to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found this behavior surprising, but it makes sense once you consider how object attributes and order of execution will work in an instance like this.

To demonstrate it for myself, I made an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

a = A(1)
a, a.a = a.a, None
```

These issue is that although the right side is evaluated all at once, the left side is still evaluated from left to right. This means `a` will reassign to `a.a` perfectly, but by the time `a.a` on the left side is evaluated, `a` will no longer have the `.a` atribute because it has been reassigned to an int.

Replacing the last line with the following has the same result, and may demonstrate the problem a bit more clearly:

```
t = a.a, None
a = t[0]
a.a = t[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider the order of assignment on the left!